# How does select all checkbox work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have to implement a functionality where I have few radio buttons, when I click on a radio button I'll get check boxes, out of which the first check box is "Select all". Rest of the check boxes are few options. When I click on any of these check boxes, a 5-star rating with label as the check box name should come up.

For example (I'm sorry that I can't post a UI picture of this) :

```
radiobutton1  radiobutton2
```

when I click on radiobutton1

```
select_all check box
abc check box
pqr check box
xyz check box
```

These check boxes will show up.
Now, If I select pqr check box, 5-star rating with a label of "pqr" will come.

```
pqr
star1 star2 star3 star4 star5
```

Now, If I select both pqr check box and xyz check box, I'll get their respective ratings :

```
pqr
star1 star2 star3 star4 star5

xyz
star1 star2 star3 star4 star5
```

If I select, "Select all" check box, then all the check boxes under it gets checked and ratings for the same will come :

```
abc
star1 star2 star3 star4 star5

pqr
star1 star2 star3 star4 star5

xyz
star1 star2 star3 star4 star5
```

I wrote code for rating, radio buttons, check boxes, everything. But I'm getting issue for "select all" checkbox. (My code has lot of other variables and it's sort of big, because this functionality is just a part of a page, so I'm not posting my code here). Also, please note that these options(abc, pqr, xyz) are dynamic and are coming from backend.

```
<div class="db-checkbox skills_options select_all hidden"><input type="checkbox" id="sa" onClick="toggle(this)"><label for="sa">Select all skills</label></div>

<div class="db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden"><input class = "skills_select" type="checkbox" value="abc" name="abc" id="a"><label for="a">abc</label></div>
<div class="db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden"><input class = "skills_select" type="checkbox" value="pqr" name="pqr" id="p"><label for="p">pqr</label></div>
<div class="db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden"><input class = "skills_select" type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz" id="x"><label for="x">xyz</label></div>
```

This is the code for the check boxes and the toggle function in select all check box is as follows :

```
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('skills_select');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

And I wrote two on click functions, one for the individual options (when I click on `abc, pqr, xyz` for the respective ratings to show up) and one for the select all options (when I click on `select all`, ratings of all options to show up). Also, notice here that for each radio button, there are check boxes of it's own.

Now, my issue is that, When I click on `select all`, all options are getting selected, when I deselect `select all`, all options are getting unchecked, but, when I select, `select all` check box, and then I uncheck any option under it, `select all` check box should also gets unchecked right? Such things are not happening and I can't figure out how I resolve this. Can you please tell me how do I make a `select all` check box work correctly that works fine in all the scenarios in javascript and jquery (when I select `select all`, and then uncheck `abc, pqr` and/or `xyz`; `select all` should get unchecked, when I select `abc, pqr` and `xyz` individually ratings for `abc, pqr, xyz` will come and now when I click on `select all`, again all shouldn't come (it's coming like this for me because i wrote two onclick functions right?); all such cases). Thank you!

Comment: TL;DR; - why can you not post picture of the UI?  Incidentally you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID and fyi an ID cannot legitimately be simply an integer

Comment: Perhaps adding the necessary HTML and Javascript would be a good idea to allow others to help?

Answer (score 2):

`"when I select, select all check box, and then I uncheck any option under it, select all check box should also gets unchecked right?"`

Is the following what you were trying to do? Incidentally I removed the ID attributes as they were invalid and then moved the `input` within the `label` to associate the two.

```js
let checker=document.getElementById('checker');
let col=document.querySelectorAll('input.skills_select');

checker.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    col.forEach(n=>n.checked=this.checked);
});

col.forEach( n=>{
  n.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if( !this.checked && checker.checked )checker.checked=false;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class='db-checkbox skills_options select_all hidden'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' id='checker'>Select all skills</label>
</div>

<div class='db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden'>
    <label><input class='skills_select' type='checkbox' value='abc' name='abc'>abc</label>
</div>
<div class='db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden'>
    <label><input class='skills_select' type='checkbox' value='pqr' name='pqr' />pqr</label>
</div>
<div class='db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden'>
    <label><input class='skills_select' type='checkbox' value='xyz' name='xyz' />xyz</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not being able to access the select all element by document.getElementById, it's giving me null. But I'm able to access it by document.getElementsByClassName, but then I'm getting error, "checker.addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: You would have to show the code you have used for clarification

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you want to add the rating part to DOM
But this code can probably help.

It is better to use the `change` event for `checkboxes`

```js
    $("#sa").on("change", function(){
        if( $(this).is(":checked" ) )
      {
        $(".skills_select").each(function(){
            if(!$(this).is(":checked" ))
            {
              
              $(this).prop('checked', true)
              $(this).change()
            }
         })
      } else
      {
        $(".skills_select").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked" ))
            {
              
              $(this).prop('checked', false)
              $(this).change()
            }
         })
      }
        
    })


    $(".skills_select").on("change", function(){
        // Get parent div
      let parent_div = $(this).closest('div');
      
// It's for example, it's better to use hidden attribute
      if( $(this).is(":checked" ) )
        $(parent_div).append("<div class='rate'> <br> star1 star2 ... </div>")
      else
        $(parent_div).find(".rate").remove()
      
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="db-checkbox skills_options select_all hidden"><input type="checkbox" id="sa" ><label for="sa">Select all skills</label></div>

    <div class="db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden"><input class = "skills_select" type="checkbox" value="abc" name="abc" id="a"><label for="a">abc</label></div>
    <div class="db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden"><input class = "skills_select" type="checkbox" value="pqr" name="pqr" id="p"><label for="p">pqr</label></div>
    <div class="db-checkbox skills_options for_rating hidden"><input class = "skills_select" type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz" id="x"><label for="x">xyz</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve the effect that you are looking for (Which is the beauty of coding). [Abronsius answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586548/3007852) is very elegant and simple. [Jialis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586853/3007852) uses JQuery and includes a suggestion to handle raitings. I'll provide a thrid different approach.

First we divide the checkboxes into sections. This is simply a wrapper div around a group of checkboxes, where the first checkbox should always be the `Select all` option. We will also make use of the `data` attribute to separate what function a checkbox serves (Select all or just a single option).

We will then grab every single checkbox on the page and bind to their `change` event, handling all checkboxes in the same function. We will use `data` attribute to seperate them and the section `div` to group them.

This gives us a very modular approach where you can easily add as many sections, checkboxes and raitings as you'd like.

```js
function showRaitingForCheckbox(checkbox) {
   /* For you to implement... */
}

function hideRaitingForCheckbox(checkbox) {
  /* For you to imeplement... */
}

/* We grab every single checkbox on this page and loop through them. */
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
checkboxes.forEach(function (element) {

    /* Bind an event listener for the 'change'. */
    element.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      let checkbox = e.target; // Checkbox that has been clicked
      let type = checkbox.dataset.id; // It's 'type', all or 'single'
      let parentNode = checkbox.parentNode; // Parent node, so that we can reach other checkboxes in this section
      let children = parentNode.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"); // All checkboxes within this section

      /* Seperate logic for clicking on 'Select all' and 'Select single option' */
      if (type == "all") {

        /* We clicked on the 'Select all' checkbox. Go through all checkboxes for this section. */
        children.forEach(function (child) {

        /* Make sure we're only targeting 'Select single option' checkboxes. */
        if (child.dataset.id == "single") {

        /* Either check or uncheck the checkbox, also toggle raitings. */
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
          child.checked = true;
          showRaitingForCheckbox(child)
        } else {
          child.checked = false;
          hideRaitingForCheckbox(child);
        }
      }
    });
  } else if (type == "single") {

    /* We clicked on a 'Select single option' checkbox, let's toggle raitings first. */
    if (checkbox.checked == true)
      showRaitingForCheckbox(checkbox);
    else
      hideRaitingForCheckbox(checkbox);

    /* Calculate how many checkboxes have been selected in this section. */
    let amountOfCheckedCheckboxes = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i].dataset.id == "single" && children[i].checked == true)
        amountOfCheckedCheckboxes++;
    }

    /* If not all checkboxes are selected, unselect the 'Select all' box, otherwise select it. */
    if (amountOfCheckedCheckboxes < children.length - 1)
      children[0].checked = false;
    else
      children[0].checked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="all">Select all</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="all">Select all</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="all">Select all</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="single">Select single option</input>
</div>
```

Funny side note: I don't think i've ever written the word `checkbox` this many times before.